# Concept Behind Making A Class Static Final in Java

Tags: java, final

I am new to Java , and at school level, i have one query can any one better explain me the concept behind it , what it's means and when to use and why .

```
public class ParentClass {
    private static final ParentClass ourInstance=new ParentClass();
    private ArrayList<Integer> arr=new ArrayList<>();
    public static ParentClass getinstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }
    private ParentClass() {

    }
    public void setList(ArrayList<Integer> al) {
        arr.addAll(al);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer>  getList(){
        return arr;
    }

}
```

I want to focus on this line `private static final ParentClass ourInstance=new ParentClass();` what it's means and when we have to declare the syntax like this ? I know we can make the class Final then no subclass can extends the final class.In the Above code the way of declaration is something different ,that's waht confused me .

Comment: First of all: You do not make the class `static final`, you make the field `ourInstance` `static final`. `static` means that this field is shared among all instances of ParentClass, `final` means that you cannot reassign this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static final ParentClass ourInstance=new ParentClass();
```

When you declare field of a class as final then you can't reassign its value after initialisation.

What it means is you cannot execute below code:

```
ParentClass otherInstance = new ParentClass();
ourInstance = otherInstance;   // Not allowed as ourInstance is final.
```

But you can perform below operations i.e. you can change fields of ourInstance by calling its setter methods: -
e.g.

```
ourInstance.setSomeMethod(someValue);   // Allowed as you are not modifying object's reference but only its properties which are not final.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know when we can make the class Final then no subclass can extends the final class.

True. But in your code, the `final` is applying to a field, which means that this static field `ourInstance` will not be modified, i.e., it will not be re-assigned to another instance.

The reason why `static` is applied here:

```
private static final ParentClass ourInstance = new ParentClass();
```

is  working with

```
public static ParentClass getinstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

private ParentClass() {
}
```

to implement the [singleton design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Comment: The instance can easily be modified - what you mean is the variable cannot be re-assigned.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is "You are creating Class constant", the word final in this context is used to create constant. And also its static, so there is no need to create an instance to access it.

You are instantiating it where its declared, because you cannot do it outside since your constructor is private. So accessing the instance of this class only possible by calling getInstance, that too already created instance is accessible. Outside its not possible to create instance. That way you are creating singleton, means only one instance of this class will be created in VM.